# creating multiple panels and displaying one panel on button click in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010

I am new to WPF and I want to create a WPF application with 5buttons. On the click of each button I want a content to be displayed on another panel. Right now I just want different images to be displayed on my right side panel on the button clicks.

Here's my XAML code:

```
<Window x:Class="GridButton.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MyFirstApp" Height="350" Width="525" Loaded="Window_Loaded">
<Viewbox Stretch="Fill" StretchDirection="Both">
<DockPanel>
    <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="left" Margin="5" Width="Auto" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="Auto">
        <Button  Content="1" Name="button2" Click="button2_Click">
       </Button>
        <Button Content="2" Name="button1" Click="button1_Click_1">
</Button>
        <Button Content="3" Name="button3"  Click="button3_Click">
          </Button>
        <Button Content="4" Name="button4" Margin="5">
          </Button>
        <Button Content="5" Name="button5" Margin="5" Click="button5_Click_1">
          </Button>
    </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Right">
            <Image Name="img1" Source="Blue Hills.jpg" Stretch="Uniform" Visibility="Hidden" ImageFailed="Image_ImageFailed" Height="257" />

        </StackPanel>

</DockPanel>
```

And my xaml.cs file contains code to display image:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

    img1.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
}
```

I could get only this far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the `Source` property of the `Image` control in code:

```
private void buttonx_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
{
    string path = ... // path to image file here
    img1.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(path));
}
```

You could easily reuse the same Click handler for all Buttons and check which one was pressed:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
{
    Button button = sender as Button;
    string path = null;
    if (button == button1)
    {
        path = ... // path to image file 1 here
    }
    else if ...

    if (path != null)
    {
        img1.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(path));
    }
}
```

If you want to remove the a child Panel (or other control) from a parent Panel and add another one, you would have to modify the Panel's [Children](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.panel.children) property:

```
<StackPanel Name="parent">   
    <StackPanel Name="child" />   
</StackPanel>  

parent.Children.Remove(child);
parent.Children.Add(...); // some other control here
```

This approach would usually make sense if you wanted to create child panels dynamically. If you want to declare everything in XAML you may put all child panels in a Grid and change their visibility as you did already.

However, you might also change the [ZIndex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.panel.zindex) attached property.

```
<Grid>
    <StackPanel Name="child1">
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Name="child2">
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Name="child3">
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

child3 is topmost by default, but now you can set `ZIndex` to some value > 0 to make another child topmost:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
{
    ...
    // reset ZIndex on previous topmost panel to 0 before
    Panel.SetZIndex(child1, 1);
}
```

Or completely omit the Button/Grid/Panel design and use a [TabControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tabcontrol.aspx).

Comment: On each button's click, I want a different Image to be displayed on the Panel. How do I set the Image to appear in the StackPanel and also in future I would be displaying different panels on the StackPanel on Button clicks.Suggest some idea for that too please

Comment: Your XAML shows that you have 5 different Click handlers, hence you can set 5 different images. Not the most efficient approach though. I'll edit my answer to give you a hint how to continue.

Comment: I get it thanks.Also could you give me a hint on how to overlay panels and display only one and hide the rest on a button click. Suppose instead of an image I want to display a panel with many contents then how should i do that?